# XSLT - Dealing with multiple child-nodes

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I've got to write and XSLT to deal with the following XML:

```
<Attachments>
    <string>http://lurl/site/Lists/Note/Attachments/image1.jpg</string>
    <string>http://lurl/site/Lists/Note/Attachments/image3.jpg</string>
</Attachments>
```

I need to output the 2 strings, although for some records there are more then 2 strings to output.

e.g.

```
<ul>
  <li>http://lurl/site/Lists/Note/Attachments/image1.jpg</li>
  <li>http://lurl/site/Lists/Note/Attachments/image3.jpg</li>
</ul>
```

Do i need a **for each** or a **while**?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any kind of iteration. Use the Identity transformation and override:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Attachments">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="string">
        <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @andyb thanks, I've included the identity transformation just beacuse it might help in general. If the sample XML in the question is as simple as showed it can be removed as shown in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

A simple [`apply-templates`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Applying-Template-Rules) should do it.

```
<xsl:template match="Attachments">
  <ul>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="string">
  <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use an `xsl:template`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <ul>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/Attachments/string">
  <li>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </li>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
<xsl:for-each select="//Attachments/string">
  <li>
    <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
  </li>
</xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```